# $Project inside find mongodb

Tags: mongodb, solr, database

It's possible to transform this:

```
db.processoDomain.aggregate([{
              $project: {
                'status': 1,
                'instancia': 1,
                'ano': 1,
                'numeroProcesso': 1,
                'partes': '$informacoesAdicionais.PARTES'
              }
            }])
```

To this:

```
db.processoDomain.find({}
              , {
                'status': 1,
                'instancia': 1,
                'ano': 1,
                'numeroProcesso': 1,
                'partes': '$informacoesAdicionais.PARTES'
              }
            )
```

Because I need to make projection in solr query, and there don't accept aggregate function.

Thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as far as I know you either have to use the aggregation pipeline with its projection stage or do it in the application layer.